# Why do I see "HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid." when connected to a wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

Good day, help me, please understand the situation:

connect to the wcf service is only obtained locally

```
http://localhost:50233/Service1.svc?wsdl
```

when tested compound from another machine on the LAN i see the error 400

```
http://computer:50233/Service1.svc?wsdl
```

i Found information that this may be due to MaxFieldLength and therefore i edited registry as advised here, but it does not alter the result.

```
C: \ Users \ user> ping computer

Pinging 192.168.0.11 with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 192.168.0.11: bytes = 32 time <1ms TTL = 127

Reply from 192.168.0.11: bytes = 32 time <1ms TTL = 127

Reply from 192.168.0.11: bytes = 32 time <1ms TTL = 127

Reply from 192.168.0.11: bytes = 32 time <1ms TTL = 127

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.11:

Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:

Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

When you stop service  the error on the remote computer is changed to

```
"Web page not available"
```

The rules of the firewall allows all incoming connections on port 50233.

When connecting to a local address

```
http://computer:50233/Service1.svc?wsdl
```

i See the same error 400.

when removing or replacing the "localhost" on IP

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50233:localhost" />
```

File \ My Documents \ IISExpress \ config \ applicationhost.config

connection becomes not available.

When you add another Binding

```
<Binding Protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50233:localhost" />

<Binding Protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50233:192.168.0.11" />
```

service when trying to start swears Program "[9632] iisexpress.exe"

failed with code -1073741816 (0xc0000008) 'An invalid handle was specified'.

Windows 8, Visual Studio 2013, use the built-IIS Express, both computers are in the same domain.

Comment: You can also do this without the config changes, using our free extension for VS called Conveyor https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Command execution (as administrator)

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://computer:50233/ user=Everyone
```

helped to change a mistake with 400 on 503

Now to see my wsdl, I just added a reference

```
<Binding Protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50233:computer" /> 
<Binding Protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50233:192.168.0.11" /> 
<Binding Protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50233:localhost" />
```

and it start working!

thank you all, it's a wonderful place

Comment: Where do you add this reference <Binding Protocol... ?

Comment: My Documents \ IISExpress \ config \ applicationhost.config

Comment: If you're wanting to do this with a web project running in Visual Studio, applicationhost.config is in [project root]\.vs\config\applicationhost.config